# Android. Calculate the number of characters that fit on the screen

Tags: android, text, view

I am writing a reader under Android. Pages are separated into different View. How to calculate how many characters fit on the screen to correctly divide the text into different View? Maybe there is a simple method to do this?
The code for adding text to Views:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView.setText(text);
            realViewSwitcher.addView(textView);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could probably make assumptions based on text size, maybe the default here would be 12dip. And then assuming that the average word length is 5 words. determining how many dips a 5 character words takes. and then taking the width and height and and divide it by that number.

Comment: Is there an easier variant? I just need to do something like reader, where the text will be split into many pages and will be scrolling.

Comment: this could work. getTextSize() to get the size of text. then getMaxEms()*(what you setMaxLines() to) to calculate total surface. Add character by character until the total surface has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) can help you. There is methods like "measureText", or "breakText". You can get a Paint object from a TextView with getPaint().

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could calculate the number of ems that fit in the textview somehow.

or perhaps you could create an algorithm that try's to fit the characters based on computerVerticalScrollRange(). Through trial and error, it could eventually find the perfect fit.